# killed в логе при запуске скрипта, запускаемого по крону

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian

Почему пишет в лог слово "killed"?

Скрипт обновляет базу, его нужно запускать периодически, чтобы цены и остатки на сайте были новыми. Размер базы данных 10 Gb.

сrontab для запуска такой:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /var/tmp/lodi.lock -c "/usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/site.ru/bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_import.php >> /var/tmp/lodi.log 2>&1"
```

В лог должен записываться результат выполнения скрипта php (загружает прайс-листы из 1c- обновляет нас сайте цены и остатки), запускаемоего кроном, однако он не записывается. Процесс крона убивала (командой top высвечивался процесс cron), перезапускала сервер, не помогло.

До этого скрипт работал месяц бесперебойно до 5 утра.

Сейчас запустила руками скрипт. 2 строка. процесс 4337. Он сейчас пропал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот это у меня было прописано в скрипте:

```
set_time_limit(0); 
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

в тех поддержке хостинга сказали "В заданиях crontab, не был указан пользователь от которого они должны выполняться. Именно это и вызывало проблему." И что надо настроить?

Comment: Системные логи посмотрите. И может он стал работать слишком долго или какую блокировку в БД ждать и вы когда крон прибивали он killed и получил ...

Comment: Если он месяц работал совершенно не значит, что какой нибудь другой процесс не заблочил таблицу. Или данных накопилось слишком много. Вообще php скрипт жрущий 2Гб памяти это как то жутковато выглядит. да и mysql 100% проца жрущий нехорошо, особенно если это в течение долгого времени.

Comment: кстати, killed он может получать если ему памяти не хватит, например

Comment: разбираться в скрипте, почему он так много памяти жрет. я бы это понял если бы у него были какие то расчетные задачи, с кучей данных, но он же просто конвертит данные из одного формата в другой, он наверняка это может делать последовательной обработкой, не удерживая в памяти такой объем. У вас размер базы вообще какой ?

Comment: вот у меня такой запрос делается долго

Comment: За один запрос mysql можно скормить 64Кб данных, значит скрипту в один момент держать в памяти более 64кб скорее всего не нужно. Смысла читать сразу 2 ГБ и потом по 64Кб скармливать я не вижу. Я не думаю что тут можно дать дельный совет что делать, скорее всего пересмотреть всю логику обмена между базами

Comment: почистить временные логи где можно?

Comment: Знать бы еще что такое "временные логи"

Comment: куда записываются временные таблицы.

Comment: Я конечно экстрасенс и не видя кода должен знать что делает ваш скрипт и куда и что он пишет. Думаю надо посмотреть в скрипте что он использует и потом вбить это в гугле. например по запросу "mysql временная таблица" написано, что mysql удаляет временную таблицу как только закрывается соединение. так что как только ваш скрипт завершается - место освобождается

Comment: *работал месяц бесперебойно* — 1. с какой периодичностью в crontab-е вызывается этот скрипт? 2. а нужно ли его вообще запускать *периодически*? 3. заложена ли в коде скрипта защита от повторного запуска, проверяет ли он наличие других экземпляров себя же и как действует при обнаружении?

Comment: 1. в течение 40 мин 2. да нужно, чтобы цены и остатки на сайте были новыми. 3.да, есть.

Comment: `в течение 40 мин` и `*/5 * * * *` (каждые пять минут) явно не соответствуют друг другу. // *что надо насторить?* в какой именно файл вы добавляете задание?

Comment: @RRR А где у вас лежит этот файл crontab и как он называется ? Кронтабы бывают двух видов: 1. "приватный" - лежат обычно в /var/spool/cron/crontabs и называются по имени пользователя под которым запускать. В них после 5 полей с датой/временем идет сразу запускаемая команда. 2. "общий" - обычно в /etc/crontab, в нем после 5 полей даты/времени пишется имя пользователя под которым запускать, после него, следующим полем идет команда

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы меня запутали, вы в начало перенесли строку, а я ее до этого в конце рассматривал. Судя по названию `/usr/bin/flock` ставит блокировку на файл и если это удалось запускает процесс, если не удалось - не запускает, таким образом одновременно работает только 1 копия

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35784/discussion-on-question-by-rrr-killed-------).